# react with JSS - how to add class to child component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jss

I have a wrapper component which handles animating the mounting and unmounting of my components, as well as passing on any other props from the parent. The wrapper adds `class` and `toggleVisibility` props to the child, so that I can add the animation css to the containing elements and alter the visibility from within the child, however I'd like to have the css applied to the root element of the child without having to alter the child's code to accommodate. This is my code:

```
<Animated visibility="initialOn" direction="down" >
  <Welcome testProp="Coool!" />
</Animated>
```

```js
export const Animated = ({
  children,
  visible,
  direction = "up",
}: Props): JSX.Element => {
  const theme: any = useTheme();
  const [show, setShow] = useState(visible === "initialOn" || visible === true);
  if (visible !== "initialOn" && visible !== "initialOff") {
    if (show !== visible) {
      setShow(visible);
    }
  }
  const transitioned = useMountTransition(show, theme.defaultTransitionSpeed);
  const toggleVisibility = () => setShow(!show);
  const animatedClass = // this contains the JSS class I want to apply to the child's root element
    transitioned && show
      ? theme.animVisible[direction]
      : theme.animInVisible[direction];

  const childrenWithProps = React.Children.map(children, (child) => {
    if (React.isValidElement(child)) {
      return React.cloneElement(child, {
        toggleVisibility,
        animatedClass,
      });
    }
    return child;
  });

  return <>{(transitioned || show) && childrenWithProps}</>;
};
```

This is the child component, you can see where I'm injecting the additional style into the JSS.

```js
export const useStyles = createUseStyles<any, any>((theme: any) => {
  const { modalOuter, animatedClass } = theme;
  return {
    splashOuter: { //container div
      ...modalOuter,
      marginLeft: "auto",
      marginRight: "auto",
      ...animatedClass, // apply animation styles
    },
  };
});

const Welcome = ({ toggleVisibility, animatedClass }: Props): JSX.Element => {
  const theme = { ...useTheme(), animatedClass }; // additional styles applied within here
  const styles = useStyles({ theme });
  return (
    <div className={styles.splashOuter}>
      <div className={styles.splashInner}>
        <button className={styles.button} onClick={toggleVisibility}>
          PROCEED
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Welcome;
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you considered creating a HigherOrderFunction that accepts any component and returns the modified component with an added parent div with the respective properties attached?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was much simpler than I expected. Wrapping the child component in a div with the styles applied worked perfectly. Thanks

```js
const childrenWithProps = React.Children.map(children, (child) => {
    if (React.isValidElement(child)) {
      return (
        <div className={styles.wrapper}>
          {React.cloneElement(child, {
            toggleVisibility,
          })}
        </div>
      );
    }
    return child;
  });
```